# Looking for a 2D Bin Packing library in Java

Tags: library, java, maven

I am looking for a general purpose 2D bin packing library in Java. One that

- is well maintained and/or has sufficient usage
- is available via Maven (optional)
- has a Apache2 or **similar** license
- is platform independent (a java wrapper for
  Google's OR tools exists but it is not guaranteed to run on all Linux distros)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!